# Esper query about group by for max(value) - SQL

Tags: sql, events, max, esper

I'm new to Esper development and I'm having a slight issue.

In SQL, i have the follow query to translate to Esper :   select max(time) from tab group by user

What I want to do is that for all the events that I have, i want to select the max(time) for every user and display it.

In Esper, i translated it the following way: select max(time) from window group by user.

However, unlike SQL, every single event that comes to the window is displayed, so i end up getting in the console all the time values for every user, and not the highest value :/  It's not doing the "group by" I assume. If you have any hints on how to solve this problem, I would gladly accept them :)

regards,

Benjamin 6

Answer (score 0):

Esper is does continuous query processing and the continuous query generates output all the time if anyone is listening. What you could do is send in all events and then use "iterate()" or you could use a fire-and-forget query or use output rate limiting such as "output every 1 minute".

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I actually tried the "output every 1 minute", but it doesn't output anything at all :/

Comment: try "output snapshot every 1 minute" instead (will output the results of the query every minute, regardless of whether there were any new events during the latest minute).

Comment: @xpa1492 i tried and i still get an empty output. Any other ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

for example if you have:
time1 = 10, user = 1 & time2 = 11, user = 1 ---> i only want to get time2=11, user =1. However in esper, it output both, which is normal. Any methods of keeping all events before applying the query?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are processing a continuous stream of events, and you're expecting to grab the maximum value out of it.

This can't be done directly, because each event in Esper is an individual entity. You can grab the maximum from an individual event, but not from multiple events. And that's what is happening in your case, you're having the maximum value out of a single valued event. Thus, you see all the events printed.

To achieve what you want, I'd suggest you should use Windows or Contexts within Esper to accumulate the events for a particular time (or, till a condition is met). Then, out of this bunch of events that you have collected in the window, you can choose the maximum value based on your condition, and then print the same.

You can refer the Espertech documentation for this [here](http://esper.espertech.com/release-5.5.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#epl-grouping-agglocal) and [here](http://esper.espertech.com/release-5.5.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#processingmodel_batch).